# Background is only shown when javascript is disabled by user

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

I'm working on this website wich relies heavilly on Javascript and jQuery (http://windowsnaarlinux.nl/). The problem is that all those object are made visible with an effect using jQuery. So when the user has disabled Javascript in their webbrowser, they see nothing but a static background.
I know I can just set everything visible and use Javascript to hide everything when the page loads so jQuery can do the effects, but this only works for small things like icons. When I use that strategy on this website, everything flashes at first, then disappears, and then comes back with a jQuery effect. This doesn't look nice.
So, is there a way to get it to show the content when Javascript is disabled? I've alreayd put the content between noscript tags as well (when a certain PHP GET parameter is given), so Google can see the content. Problem is that the navigation bar and the content area are hidden unless jQuery makes them visible.

Comment: I wouldn't call it the "answer," but take a look at general progressive enhancement techniques.  Here's a decent place to start.  http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/progressive-enhancement/
All-in-all, I'd say make your webpage look the way you want without javascript, and then use javascript to do the extra (but you'll always have a "flash" between the original and the javascript; length depends on client hardware)

Comment: why not put downgraded content (with styles etc.) inside the noscript tags? include a simple navigation bar, et voila.

Comment: @alex Actually i'm starting to think that that would indeed be the best solution. You might wanna submit that as an answer in stead of a comment ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real solution to your problem apart from redesigning your page so that one version is built by javascript and another kept inside noscript tags.

You could run a javascript redirect to a javascript only version outside of any `onload` and just build the landing page as html but there is no guarantee as to what order a users browser will render in and the speed at which the redirect will function.

My best advice to you is if you need your page to function without javascript then don't build javascript into it's core (do you need javascript to load everything on your page?)

Comment: "do you need javascript to load everything on your page?" << No. It's loaded allright and put between noscript tags. Problem is that the container for the content is invisible.

Comment: aha! does something like: <noscript><style type="text/css">.container{display:block}</style></noscript> (assuming you hid them with display:none;) i.e. if there is no javascript, override the styles, so the content is shown. better yet, you could load different style.css files, one with script, one without.

Comment: Yeah... the problem is that the <noscript> tag is only allowed in the body of the page, and the <style> tag in the head.

Comment: ;) thats right, I accidentally mistook it with scripts, that are possible to be applied at the end of an html file. however, you can nevertheless supply an inline display override to the div. which begs the question how you are supplying the content in the current noscript environment. is it a duplicate or is it the actual hidden data? in any case, pulling the script-enabled-style.css through javascript (not jquery!) is also too slow/makes the browser go flashy?

Comment: "pulling the script-enabled-style.css through javascript (not jquery!) is also too slow/makes the browser go flashy?" << I'll try, probably will unless I can tell it to not load until the CSS file is loaded. The content between de noscript tags in a copy pulled in through PHP.

Comment: I ender up copying most of the content between noscript tags, putting some things in seperate files and tweaking some HTML and CSS thingies using PHP, but it works. As the different contents of the frame where loaded from seperate files into a certain area in the page, I could do that using PHP in the between-noscripts-tags version.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is the progressive enhancement method - assume that everyone coming in has a braindead/ancient/obsolete browser, and make your landing/home page be a plain-jane "you must upgrade to something less useless" page. On there you'd have some JS that automatically redirects to the enhanced page.

Old/bad browsers won't do the redirect, and see the upgrade text. Modern browsers will jump to the new page automatically and life goes on.

Comment: They already get a message saying they need to enable Javascript. But I just want the website to work for everyone. Part of the targeted public have Javascript disabled in their browsers.

Comment: If the site is based on JS, and users don't have JS, there's not much you can do. start with lowest common denominator and enable things as the browsers' capabilities grow.

Answer (score 1):

Per default, browsers with javascript turned off render additional content inside given `<noscript>` tags. see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

so, basically, it should be absolutely possible to show a downstripped version of the content.

I guess in this case, the main problem was, that the content container (that probably got pulled from the according php call), was hidden. so it did not show up.

the solution to this is, alas, also the weak spot of this approach: you wouldn't need to hide the content in the `<noscript>` tag in the first place, since it is not rendered when the browser supports javascript. the point is, that the content is being printed twice: one hidden (which either gets shown through javascript or stays hidden) and one inside the `<noscript>` tags (which either is being ignored by the browser or becomes visible). however, that means that the transfered data is being doubled. which is not good practice.

so even though this should answer the question, other answers in this post should be considered a better approach.